# Как сделать отступ всему выделенному тексту?

Tags: поддержка

Чтобы текст отобразился как код на SO нужно делать 4 отступа.
Как быстро делать эти отступы?

Comment: Выделить код и нажать CTRL+K

Answer (score 4):

Достаточно ставить ***тройные обратные кавычки*** до и после кода (```)

(также после первых тройных кавычек можно написать без пробела ЯП, чтобы отобразилась подсветка синтаксиса)